# How To Display information in PDF format in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to display some copy right agreement in pdf format in EditText or TextView. How to do that in Android ? Are there any APIs or any sample codes ? I will be waiting for valuable reply.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Android does not natively support pdfs (and EditText/TextViews certainly don't!) You could check to see if [Adobe Reader for Android](http://blogs.adobe.com/adobereader/2010/05/introducing_adobe_reader_for_a.html) is installed, or you can (and this is what I recommend) convert whatever agreement you're trying to show to plaintext and display it in a TextView. If you need more formatting control, you could try converting your agreement to HTML and showing it in a WebView.